# getting this error while running react native project

Tags: react-native, android-studio

npx react-native run-android
info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...

> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED
> 1 actionable task: 1 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.

> Failed to query the value of task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin' property 'compilerRunner$kotlin_gradle_plugin'.
> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation. Make sure Kotlin compilation is running on a JDK, not JRE.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.

> Failed to query the value of task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin' property 'compilerRunner$kotlin_gradle_plugin'.
> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation. Make sure Kotlin compilation is running on a JDK, not JRE.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\shubsant\gamificationApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\shubsant\gamificationApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\shubsant\gamificationApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\shubsant\gamificationApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I have setup the environmental variables but still getting this error....

JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre

JAVA_BIN
C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin

nodejs
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin

npm
C:\Users\kkesarka\AppData\Roaming\npm

i have setup this variables as per my colleagues had set up